# 3D mapping on spinning 2D unit, and Lidar Resources?

Tags: lidar

Very new to Lidar but I am seeking to use Lidar in a project and have a Spinning 2d unit I made with garmins v3HP but. Now I am caught up on mapping, I was wondering if it was possible to do things like what is shown in the image with a spinning 2D. EDIT: I forgot to mention if anybody has any good resources on Lidar it would be a great help to me as I am new[image]

Thank you.

Comment: it is unclear what the image is supposed to demonstrate ..... the color coding in the image is not obvious .... so it is unclear how the image relates to the use of Lidar

Comment: Hi jsotola, It seems I have found a solution to my problem someone else pitched in, but I found that online under a lidar mapping article/segement on lidar and it was under a "point cloud map". I was curious if this was possibile with my as someone pointed out "lidar lite" rangefinder.

Comment: here is an image that more closely represents what you are trying to do .... https://ai2-s2-public.s3.amazonaws.com/figures/2016-11-08/ef199e8e4fdd3d3c0f78b62eb1b35ff6afcc2c3f/0-Figure1-1.png

Comment: That is actually what I had in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a pseudo 3D lidar with a 2D one. You have to add a motor or more specifically a servo that tilts the LIDAR. You can then continuously tilt the LIDAR and just integrate all the measurements together to form a 3D point cloud. If you look at this [paper](http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/rss10/p07.pdf) you can see an example of how they set this up in Fig 2. You can also use that paper as a reference for building your LIDAR mapping software.

Other papers you can take a look at with open source implementations are 
[BLAM](https://github.com/erik-nelson/blam),
[HDL graph SLAM](https://github.com/koide3/hdl_graph_slam),
and many more just google LIDAR SLAM or LIDAR mapping.

Also you do actually need a proper 2D LIDAR to do any sort of mapping. From your post it looks like you have this https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/578152 which is called a LIDAR-lite, but is basically just a range finder.

Comment: I just read through some of those, thank you. And that psuedo 3d idea doesn't seem to bad on paper. But by your comment you mean it can only do range finding? What do you recommend as a proper Lidar, I don't mind spending a fair amount of cash on one.

Comment: Yes the lidarlite will only give you range. Problem with Lidars are that they are quite expensive. In the past I have had some success with https://www.robotshop.com/en/hokuyo-utm-03lx-laser-scanning-rangefinder.html . If you need something cheaper this seems to be the cheapest 2D lidar https://www.robotshop.com/en/hokuyo-urg-04lx-ug01-scanning-laser-rangefinder.html

Comment: The one you listed is fair enough for me. Im okay with spending anywhere from 1,000-1500. Thank you! But some I'm seeing are quite expensive I do agree, thanks again for all your help.